# Mapquest coordinates : what system?

Tags: javascript, mapping, coordinate-systems, autodesk-forge, mapquest

I am trying to display a map using some link to call a mapquest map, like [this](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/static-map-api/v5/examples/basic/map-bounding-box/). This map is supposed to be displayed under a 3D model.

This 3D model is displayed using Forge. Strange thing, I can only get one point's coordinates on the model, but I do not know exactly where this point is...

I use javascript/node.js.react and mapquest.

It seems I have a problem of superposition between my map and my 3D object. To get the map, I use WGS84 coordinates. But there is an offset between my 3D building and its correct position on the map... It may be partly due to the fact that I do not know exactly which point I have the coordinates, but the model appears like on a corner of the map, so I think this is also due to some problem with coordinates.

So I wanted to check, are coordinates used to get mapquest's map WGS84 coordinates ? Or is it something else ? Has anyone encountered this kind of problem before ?

Comment: [MapQuest uses OpenStreetMap](http://hello.mapquest.com/attributions/), at least in part. And according to one of their wiki pages [OpenStreetMap uses the WGS84 system](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Converting_to_WGS84) so MapQuest would also need to use that system.

Comment: Alright, so the problem is not in relation with coordinates system. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The MapQuest map returned will contain the given bounding box, but since there is a very finite number of zoom levels (20), the map may have larger bounds than those requested. So if the center lines up and then as the image gets farther and farther away from the expected position closer to the edges, this may be contributing to the issue. I haven't tried this superimposition but this is the first potential issue that I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any details about your model, so I assume you're using the Revit model.

As I know, Forge platform doesn't play well with GIS information currently. Apologizing for any inconvenience caused. However, you can use the following codes to disable the centralize behavior of the Forge Viewer (after v.3.1), if your Revit models are placed with some GIS coordinates in Revit shared coordinates system. After this, you could do some coordinate conversions to map model points from viewer coordinate system to the GIS's.

```
var loadOptions = {
  applyRefPoint: true,
  globalOffset: { x:0, y:0, z:0 }
};

this.viewer.loadModel(
            svfUrl, 
            loadOptions,
            onLoadModelSuccess,
            onLoadModelError
);
```

Here are some references for Revit shared coordinate:

1. https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Suggested-workflow-with-shared-coordinates-in-Revit.html
2. https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Revit-shared-coordinate-from-geolocation-GPS-to-UTM-coordinate.html

BTW, our InfraWorks team is looking for companies and developers who can help us narrow down the use cases, please refer here for the detail: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/call-input-infraworks-api

Comment: Update : the team checked the 3D object and the problem was coming from it. Seems the bounding box was bigger than it should be, probably because there was some useless object left with the object in Revit. Now the 3D object is well centered.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Eason Kang, this may be useful when trying to use real world coordinates in the viewer. I still don't know what point I have the coordinates of, but at least it is better now than before.